# [monaca]動的に作った要素にフォーカスを合わせるには？

Tags: monaca

はじめまして、
Monacaにおいて動的に要素(テキストフォーム)を作り、そのうち最初のものにフォーカスを合わせるということをしたくて、以下のようにコードを書いたのですが、

```
function drawAnsSheet(){
    var text_form = "";
    for(i=0; i < digits; i++){
        text_form = text_form + '<INPUT type="text" class="class1" id="col' + i + '">';
    }

    $("#call_text").html(text_form);
    $('input:visible').eq(0).focus();
}
```

Chromeではうまく最初の要素にフォーカスが合ったのですが、Monacaですと、フォーカスが合いませんでした。フォーカスを合わせるにはどうすればいいのでしょうか。
よろしくお願い致します。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

タイミングの問題の様な気がします（画面に要素が表示される前に`focus()`が呼ばれている）。
`onload`とか`setTimeout`でタイミングをずらしてみると違った結果が出るのではないでしょうか。

もし、サンプルのメモ帳アプリのように`changePage`を使用しており、かつ移動先のページに追加した要素があるのであれば、ページが表示された時にフォーカスを合わせるようにするとうまくいくのではないかと思います。

少し分かりにくいかもしれませんがサンプルです（メモ帳アプリをベースにしています）。

index.html

```
<!-- TOP Page -->
<div data-role="page" id="TopPage">
    <header data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-theme="c">
        <h1>Monaca Memo</h1>
        <a href="#AddPage" data-icon="plus" class="ui-btn-right">Add</a>
    </header>
</div>

<!-- Add Memo Page -->
<div data-role="page" id="AddPage">
    <section id="call_text">
    </section>
</div>
```

javascript

```
//// append input element
function appendForm() {
    var text_form = "";
    for(i=0; i < 5; i++){
        text_form = text_form + '<INPUT type="text" class="class1" id="col' + i + '">';
    }

    $("#call_text").html(text_form);
}

//// focus element
function focusElement() {
  $('input:visible').eq(0).focus();
}

///// Called when app launch
function onReady() {
    appendForm();

    // AddPageが表示されたら先頭の要素にフォーカスを合わせる
    $('#AddPage').on('pageshow', function(event, ui) {
      focusElement();
    });
}

$(onReady); // on DOMContentLoaded
```

Comment: ありがとうございました。
やはりタイミングの問題のようでした。

これそのものではないのですが、タイミングをずらして表示するようにしたらフォーカスが合うようになりました。